# Specify a worksheet to combine - Office Scripts

Tags: javascript, excel, typescript, office-scripts

The two sample codes below are retrived from Combine worksheets into a single workbook - Office Scripts documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/resources/samples/combine-worksheets-into-single-workbook

For a workbook that contains multiple worksheets, is it possible to combine a specific worksheet that has the same name or the first/last sheet in the workbook?

```js
/**
 * This script returns the values from the used ranges on each worksheet.
 */
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook): WorksheetData[]
{
  // Create an object to return the data from each worksheet.
  let worksheetInformation: WorksheetData[] = [];

  // Get the data from every worksheet, one at a time.
  workbook.getWorksheets().forEach((sheet) => {
    let values = sheet.getUsedRange()?.getValues();
    worksheetInformation.push({
       name: sheet.getName(),
       data: values as string[][]
    });
  });

  return worksheetInformation;
}

// An interface to pass the worksheet name and cell values through a flow.
interface WorksheetData {
  name: string;
  data: string[][];
}
```

```js
/**
 * This script creates a new worksheet in the current workbook for each WorksheetData object provided.
 */
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook, workbookName: string, worksheetInformation: WorksheetData[])
{
  // Add each new worksheet.
  worksheetInformation.forEach((value) => {
    let sheet = workbook.addWorksheet(`${workbookName}.${value.name}`);

    // If there was any data in the worksheet, add it to a new range.
    if (value.data) {
      let range = sheet.getRangeByIndexes(0, 0, value.data.length, value.data[0].length);
      range.setValues(value.data);
    }
  });
}

// An interface to pass the worksheet name and cell values through a flow.
interface WorksheetData {
  name: string;
  data: string[][];
}
```

I have tried to modify the code for a while with no success. Any ideas are much much appreciated.

Comment: What is the error? Also, you cannot have two sheets with the same name.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. The example works fine, with no error.  I am trying to modify it. 
For example, I have two Excel files called A and B.  A has two sheets, called sheet 1 and sheet 2, while B has one sheet called sheet 1. After running the example flow, A.sheet1, A.sheet2 and B.sheet1 are all added to the combined Excel file.
My motivation is to get rid of A.sheet2.

Comment: Then show what you have edited and people can see what might be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After reading some Office Script tutorials, it seems to be a very simple question.

I just replace the loop with all worksheets called "A" and it works.

from

```
workbook.getWorksheets().forEach((sheet) => {
```

to

```
const sheet = workbook.getWorksheet('A');
```